# Does T'Chaka actually have Black Panther powers in Civil War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, black-panther

**Beware:** Spoilers for *Captain America: Civil War* and *Black Panther*.

In *Captain America: Civil War*, T'Chaka is the King of Wakanda, and I understand that the Kings of Wakanda hold the power of the black panther.

> Yet we see T'Chaka die in an explosion while delivering his speech for the Sokovia Accords.

How does he die here if he's got the superhuman strength, endurance, durability and etc. of the black panther?

Comment: Related: [How and why did T'Challa have the Black Panther power already?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85757/how-and-why-did-tchalla-have-the-black-panther-power-already)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

At the time of *Civil War*, T'Chaka was no longer the Black Panther, T'Challa was. According to the official prequel comic, [*Black Panther: Prelude*](https://comicstore.marvel.com/Marvels-Black-Panther-Prelude-2017-1-of-2/digital-comic/46069?r=1), the mantle of the Black Panther was passed on to T' Challa many years earlier, around the time that the events of *Iron Man* were occurring.

So, when the explosion happened, T'Chaka was just a normal person, as susceptible to serious injury as anyone else.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why T'challa was able to use the mantle of the black panther immediately to capture the winter soldier.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Doesn't the black panther get his powers from that flower? Yet we see in the black panther film that multiple people can have that power at the same time. So how would T'Chaka "lose" his power?

Comment: @theonlygusti: He may simply stop using it.

Comment: @theonlygusti There is only one Black Panther at a time traditionally. Multiple Black Panthers existed in the movie due to a break from tradition.

Comment: @theonlygusti As you may also recall from the Black Panther film the Wakandans have an "antidote" to the powers given by the Heart-shaped Herb.  Nothing physically prevents there from being multiple Black Panthers, however it is tradition that there be only one.

Comment: @theonlygusti The "antidote" is used each time T'Challa fights a challenge for the throne, in order to make the challenge fair.

Comment: @EldritchWarlord I think that is an important part of an answer